# How to access my working angular 2 app on a VM

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have developed an Angular 2 app, and on my local machine, when I say, `npm start`, it gives me a string such as

> Serving C:\Users\pepperboy\myangularproject at http://127.0.0.1:8080

It also launches the browser, that I can hit directly.

However, when I run it on my Amazon ec2 virtual machine, running `npm start` does not give me anything. I just get back the terminal, with the cursor on the next line. Consequently, I do not know, how to access my app.

My amazon EC2's url is the following

```
http://ec2-35-167-53-209.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

And so, I tried to access my app as,

```
http://ec2-35-167-53-209.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080
```

However, it just circles for a bit, and comes back saying,

> This site can’t be reached
>
> ec2-35-167-53-209.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com took too long to
>   respond.

I have also tried,
`http://35.167.53.209:8080/` with the same result, ( circles and gives the same message as above - This site can’t be reached )

EDIT : I have enabled HTTP Port 80 in the Amazon ec2 security settings from the dropdown, I initially had it set to `All traffic`. I did not see anything that matches 8080. I still am not able to access the link `http://ec2-35-167-53-209.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080`. PS : I have NOT restarted the vm

[image]

EDIT2 : I have included port 8080, see image below, still having trouble hitting http://ec2-35-167-53-209.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080
[image]

Comment: circles and says? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Have you configured an access list to permit access to port 8080?

Comment: @AtticusLiu, edited my post. Sorry about that. It basically does not load.

Comment: @brandonscript, hmm, I haven't done anything specifically, but I also have many other sites which are running on this VM, and I'm able to access all of these sans problem.

Comment: I'd check that first — make sure the port is at least accessible. Next check the Node logs.

Comment: Did you open port `8080` in the EC2 server's security group?

Comment: @MarkB, I have enabled port 80. Please see edit above.

Comment: @brandonscript I have enabled port 80. Please see edit above.

Comment: If your server is listening on port 8080, you need to open 8080, not 80.

Comment: @brandonscript, I would like to do the same, but from the dropdown list ( image above ), which one corresponds to 8080?

Comment: You have to create a custom TCP rule for 8080:8080

Comment: @brandonscript, 8080 or 8080:8080 ? I have added 8080, please see edit 2 above.

Comment: Looks like the port is open now, but your service still isn't accessible. It's no longer timing out though.

Answer (score 0):

check your iptables on EC2 settings? if it was enabled? you should open 8080, and you can use command `netstat -ntlp | grep 8080`, check your node service

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your server socket is bound to the loopback IP address 127.0.0.1 instead of the "all IP addresses" symbolic IP 0.0.0.0 (note this is NOT a netmask).

If this the case, you can send the bind ip to the listen function, where you put the port. Something like:

listen(8080, "0.0.0.0")